# prevent json encode from returning arrays as strings

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I get the following json response when I query my database:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"my name","street":"Sava Burica","city":"Belgrade","state":"Zemun","zip":"11080","country":"Serbia","giftwrap":null,"products":"[{\"count\":2,\"id\":1,\"price\":275,\"name\":\"Kayak\"},{\"count\":1,\"id\":2,\"price\":48.95,\"name\":\"Lifejacket\"}]"}]
```

It is all good except that the `products` value is a string and it should be an array.

I am using Laravel 5.3 as my framework but I don't think that makes a difference.

Can I somehow force it to return arrays as arrays and not as strings?

Comment: the `products` value looks double JSON encoded. Can you include the code that generates this JSON?

Comment: it's a laravel query, DB::table('orders')->get(); and in the db the column is like so: [{"count":2,"id":1,"price":275,"name":"Kayak"},{"count":1,"id":2,"price":48.95,"name":"Lifejacket"}]

Comment: It's saved in the DB with JSON format?

Comment: yes. angularjs is being used on the frontend.

Comment: Well, then your "products" is already a string. You should decode it, insert it into your object and encode the whole thing. What you are seeing there is what @Don'tPanic said, a double json encoded object.
PD: you shouldn't save json structures in a relational database tho..

Comment: Just because angular sends JSON doesn't mean you have to directly store that JSON. I would recommend decoding it and using it to populate product entities instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the main string your products is also JSON String encoded data, so all you need to do to decode it is

```
$s = '[{"id":1,"name":"my name","street":"Sava Burica","city":"Belgrade","state":"Zemun","zip":"11080","country":"Serbia","giftwrap":null,"products":"[{\"count\":2,\"id\":1,\"price\":275,\"name\":\"Kayak\"},{\"count\":1,\"id\":2,\"price\":48.95,\"name\":\"Lifejacket\"}]"}]';
$address = json_decode($s,true);

$s = $address[0]['products'];
$address[0]['products'] = json_decode($s,true);
print_r($address);
```

This returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => my name
            [street] => Sava Burica
            [city] => Belgrade
            [state] => Zemun
            [zip] => 11080
            [country] => Serbia
            [giftwrap] => 
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 2
                            [id] => 1
                            [price] => 275
                            [name] => Kayak
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 1
                            [id] => 2
                            [price] => 48.95
                            [name] => Lifejacket
                        )

                )

        )

)
```